React useHookState - resetState
I use useHookState for statemanagement in react.
My example state got an defaultState.
I want to reset my current state to the defaultState when I call resetState
Is there a way that is prettier than my code? It works, but I dont want to set all nested states explicit (c: { ...defaultTestNestedState })
export const defaultTestNestedState = {
    x: "Hello",
    y: "World",
    z: true
}

export const defaultTestState = {
    a: null,
    b: string
    c: { ...defaultTestNestedState }
}

const state = hookstate<DefaultTestState>({ ...defaultTestState }))

export const useTestState = () => useHookstate(state).value

export const resetTestState = () => {
    state.set({ ...defaultTestState, c: { ...defaultTestNestedState} })
}

What I'm looking for is a clean solution like:
export const resetTestState = () => {
    state.set({ ...defaultTestState })
}

